# Automatically move the divs on the left and right of a center div below the center div using only css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know styling divs inline will automatically wrap the divs to the next line if they don't fit in the viewing window, and that this is used in some situations for a quick and dirty mobile version of a site.

I want to do that, but with both sides simultaneously. It will make more sense when you check out the jsfiddle. Is this even possible with css, or is it not powerful enough?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.a {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  float:none;
  border: 1px solid blue;  
  background-color: yellow; 
}

.b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  float:none;
  border: 1px solid blue;    
  background-color: yellow; 
}

.c {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:right;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;    
  background-color: yellow; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div> <div class="a">should end up below on left</div> <div class="b">center div should end up on top</div> <div class="c">should end up below on right</div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for transition? http://jsfiddle.net/faria/udqtgxsd/ Maybe this is helpful too?  http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex and the order attribute. This is an example. You just need to configure it to your needs

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.box {
   width: 20%;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid blue;  
   background-color: yellow; 
}
.box.a {
  order: 1;
}
.box.b {
  width:30%;
  order: 2;
}
.box.c {
  margin-left: auto;
  order: 3;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .box.a  {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 0;
    order: 2;
  }
  .box.b {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  .box.c {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="wrapper"> 
   <div class="a box">should end up below on left</div> 
   <div class="b box">center div should end up on top</div> 
   <div class="c box">should end up below on right</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```